# Bad excess while accessing core data Entity

Tags: core-data, swift4, exc-bad-access

I am trying to fetch some record from some entity , but when trying to fetch frequently i am getting Bad Access error ,and app is crashing . please help .

```
 var mContext:NSManagedObjectContext! = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


 func getAllRoomName() -> [String] {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwitchMO> = SwitchMO.fetchRequest()

        var arrRoomNames = [String]()

        do {
           if let  arrSwitchesMo = try? mContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [SwitchMO]
           {

            for switchMo in arrSwitchesMo ?? []
            {
                arrRoomNames.append(switchMo.roomName ?? "")
            }

            }

        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }

        arrRoomNames = Array(Set(arrRoomNames))
        return arrRoomNames;
    }
```

**Bad Access Error**

[image]

How can i get rid of this , Please help me .

Comment: Change from `try?` to `try` and see if you get an error during `fetch()`

Comment: `let  arrSwitchesMo = try mContext.fetch(fetchRequest)` changed to this , again it crashed @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a specific fetch request a type cast is redundant. And if you are using `do catch` don't `try?`

```
func getAllRoomName() -> [String] {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwitchMO> = SwitchMO.fetchRequest()

    var arrRoomNames = [String]()

    do {
       let arrSwitchesMo = try mContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
       for switchMo in arrSwitchesMo {
            arrRoomNames.append(switchMo.roomName ?? "")
       }
       arrRoomNames = Array(Set(arrRoomNames))

    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
    return arrRoomNames
}
```

However you should make a function *can throw* if this function on its part contains a `throw`ing function

```
func getAllRoomName() throws -> [String] {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwitchMO> = SwitchMO.fetchRequest()

    var arrRoomNames = [String]()
    let arrSwitchesMo = try mContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for switchMo in arrSwitchesMo {
        arrRoomNames.append(switchMo.roomName ?? "")
    }
    return Array(Set(arrRoomNames))
}
```

If the code still crashes then the managed object context is `nil`. Declare the context **non-optional** as suggested in the Core Data template.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/I86Pjp0.png , please see this same i tried again crashed . catch block is not called , it is showing bad access

Comment: As I wrote then `mContext` is `nil`.

Comment: No ,it is not `nil` i have checked that too, see  https://pasteboard.co/I86RXT83.png . , i'll check the fetchRequest also

Comment: What's in the stack trace? Use the debugger. There must be a description of the exception reason. And if the context is not `nil` why do you annotate it as implicit unwrapped **optional**??

Comment: Nothing is showing in stack track that's why i am not able to understand why it is crashing ,without any logs  see. https://pasteboard.co/I86Uwpg.png

Comment: Is the Exception Breakpoint set? If not, set it. And open the Variables View in the debug console. And a fetch request cannot be `nil` please read the warning.

Comment: No breakpoint is not set , and  `fetch request` it can't be nil ,i was just checking in case if it is option of not , but nothing worked .

Comment: Never add temporary code to check for `nil`, ***use the debugger***. Set breakpoints and view variables.

Comment: i checked with breakpoints , no object is nil, and it is not crashing when adding some breakpoint , and in general , it is not crashing every time , when i am  trying to fetch frequently then happening .